# What is Machine.config, Web.config, App.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me What is the difference among Machine.config, Web.config, App.config?

Answer (score 10):

They're all .NET XML configuration files, the API for working with them is called `System.Configuration` (and it isn't the easiest to work with, unfortunately).

**`machine.config`** sets the configuration for all .NET applications (of the same CLR version) running on an installation of Windows (i.e. a computer machine). This file is stored under `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%version%\CONFIG`. (Note that .NET 3.0 and 3.5 do not have their own machine.config because they use the 2.0 CLR).

**`applicationHost.config`** sets the configuration for IIS which is then inherited by IIS' child objects (such as Websites and Application Pools). This file is located in IIS' folder, for the "real" IIS this is `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`, for IIS Express this is `%programfiles%\IIS Express\AppServer`. [You can read more on MSDN](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig).

**`web.config`** was originally ASP.NET-specific and used to set configuration on a per-application and per-directory basis.

- Certain configuration items only take effect if they're in the web.config file in an Application Scope's root (a "magic" type of folder in IIS, also where the `bin` directory lives).
- In IIS7.0 and later the web.config file is also used to store local IIS configuration as an alternative to `applicationHost.config`, for example if you want to store configuration directly in the filesystem (so you can physically move directory trees and preserve configuration without needing to alter applicationHost.config - either directly or using IIS Manager).

  - You can direct IIS Manager to use web.config instead of applicationHost.config by using the "Configuration Editor" option in Features View in a tree node.
- Configuration is inherited by child directories and can be overridden (so if `/foo` has a web.config file, then `/foo/bar` can have its own web.config that overrides or extends settings defined in `/foo`'s configuration.

  - Confusingly, there is also the `<location>` element which lets you set and override a directory's child configuration from within a parent's config file.

**`app.config`** is not an an actual filename (except during development), and refers to EXE-specific configuration for desktop and console applications. The config file lives in the same folder as the `*.exe` itself and has the same name as the program (e.g. "MyProgram.exe" will have a config file called "MyProgram.config"). Visual Studio renames "app.config" to "MyProgram.exe.config” when it deploys the config file during the build process. App.config does not apply to ASP.NET projects.